# What is the value of $\lim {\rm sup}_{n \to \infty} (x/n)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Just a small question is the $\limsup_{n \to \infty} (x/n) = \infty$ .

Just getting confused since two variables are involved

I am solving the following problem from Kenneth Ross

> For $x \in [0,\infty)$ , let $f_n= \frac xn$
>
> a) Find $f(x) = \lim f_n(x)$
>
> b) Determine whether $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$
>
> c) Determine whether $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[0,\infty)$

I found the following solution online

[image]

So how is the solution arguing that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} (x/n) = \infty$ .

Comment: Do you mean $\limsup_{n\to\infty}$? If not, which set is the supremum of?

Comment: Yes limit supremum

Comment: In that case, for a fixed $x$, $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac xn=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac xn = 0$. You can simply factor the $x$ out.

Comment: Ohh , so for a fixed x the answer is zero

Answer (score 2):

The variable $x$ can be factored out as it does not depend on the lim sup variable $n$. Thus,
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{n}
= x \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}
= x \cdot 0 = 0 \quad \forall \, x \,.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The argument doesn't involve $\limsup_{n\to\infty}$. For each $n$, you define
$$d_n=\sup\{|f_n(x)-f(x)|:x\in S\} $$
You have uniform convergence on $S$ if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty}d_n=0$. As a contrapositive, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}d_n\ne 0$, then you don't have uniform convergence. Note that for a fixed $n$, you take the supremum as $x$ varies throughout $S$ ($=[0,\infty)$ in part c). As the textbook shows,
$$\sup\{|f_n(x)-f(x)|:x\in S\}=\sup\left\{\left|\frac{x}{n}\right|:x\in [0,\infty)\right\}=\infty $$ 
therefore
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}d_n=\infty $$
which implies $f_n(x)$ is not uniformly convergent on $[0,\infty)$